# CodeIgniter: file won't upload

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

I'm new to using the file upload class in CodeIgniter.  I haven't been able to get their sample script to work.  I set the permissions of the uploads folder to 755 like they instructed.  I keep getting an error that I did not select a file even though if I echo the $_POST the file is there.  Here is my code.  Can someone help?

```
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '10000';
    //$config['max_width']  = '1024';
    //$config['max_height']  = '768';

    $file = $this->input->post('file');

    //echo 'file = ' . $file;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload($file))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($error); echo '</pre>';
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `$this->upload->do_upload` you need to specify the name of the upload `input` not the post value of the file.  So for the input below.

```
<input type="file" name="upload" />
```

You would put

```
$this->upload->do_upload("upload");
```

Comment: Well, that worked, but now I am getting an invalid path for file upload.  I have the full path correct and set the permissions now to 777.  Still I get the error.  Thoughts?

Comment: @shummel7845 this is normally how I set mine `$config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."uploads";`  The doc root call will get you to the base of the html directory then from there you just need to specify where to save it

Comment: I was reading something about how every folder about the uploads folder had to be writable, but when I did that to the public_html folder I got a 403 error for the site.  I now have the path as the full http:// path. I tried var_dump(is_dir('/upload/')); and I get false.  What do I need to do to get the permissions correct?  Terminal?

Comment: @shummel7845 the ONLY folder that needs to be writable is the actual folder you are writing to.  never have the public_html folder writable

Comment: That's what I thought.  Apparently, the writer didn't know what he was talking about.